# No entiendo qué hace range en Python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código y no entiendo qué es lo que hace `x=list(range(10,1,2))`; o sea, me da una lista vacía, pero no entendería por qué o para qué se usa el `range` en este caso.

```
def main():
    x=list(range(10, 1, 2))
    print(x)
    
main()
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste buscar una respuesta? Podrías mirar la documentación de la función `range` y practicar algunos ejemplos. Si aún te quedan dudas, puedes hacer pregunta ya más concretas.

Answer (score 5):

Como dijo Jack el destripador, vamos por partes

#### ¿Qué es `range`?

*Range* tiene la sintaxis `range(start, stop, step)`. Este constructor devuelve una secuencia inmutable (un tipo de objeto en Python) que representa un [conjunto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunto) ordenado de números enteros. Este objeto es llamado *rango*.

Veamos qué significa cada argumento:

- start: Desde qué número empieza el rango (este número estará dentro del rango). Por default es 0.
- stop: Hasta qué numero llega el rango (este número NO estará dentro del rango)
- step: La cantidad que se debe sumar al número anterior para llegar al siguiente. Por default es 1.

Por ejemplo `range(1, 10, 2)` incluye los números `1`, `3`, `5`, `7` y `9`.

Por sugerencia de @christian agregué esta explicación extra sobre range:
El constructor range no implementa repetición ni concatenación. Eso significa que un numero no pueden repetirse y dos rangos no se pueden sumar.
Por ejemplo hacer range(10)+range(20) nos dará un error.

#### ¿Por qué lo convertimos a una lista?

Pero, como dije antes, `range` es un objeto que representa un conjunto. NO se trata de una lista ni una tupla. Por lo que si lo quieres en forma de lista, debes convertirlo a una.

#### ¿Por qué devuelve una lista vacía?

Bueno, tu rango empieza en 10 y termina en 1. Si a 10 le vas sumando 2 nunca llegarás a 1. Cuando este tipo de escenarios sucede, el rango se considera vacío.
Si conviertes un rango vacío en una lista, esta conversión devolverá una lista vacía.

#### step como valor negativo

Step también puede ser negativo. Recuerda que una resta puede ser considerada una suma de un numero negativo.
Por ejemplo `range(10, 1, -2)` devolverá un rango que incluye los números `10`, `8`, `6`, `4`, `2`.

#### Solución

Aunque no la has pedido en tu pregunta, aquí te dejo la solución:

En lugar de que step sea positivo, hazlo negativo:

```
range(10, 1, -2)
```

Así se le irá sumando -2 a 10 y se llegará a 1.

#### Referencias

Esta respuesta fue escrita por mí pero fue mejorada en base a la documentación oficial de Python. Aquí te dejo la [documentación de la función range](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Comment: iba a escribir una respuesta pero la tuya se asemeja mucho a la que tenía en mente, muy bien explicado :D

Comment: Gracias Christian :D Debería responder más seguido a los comentarios... No estaría mal...

Comment: Buena edición, no había pensado en ponerlo de esa manera!

Comment: Bueno ahora esta mejor :)

Comment: algo que puedes añadir es que la función range no implementa repetición ni concatenación, pues range solo representa secuencias con patrones estrictos

Answer (score -1):

`range(10, 1, 2)`

En tu ejemplo estas creando una secuencia de números comenzando con el número 10, el cual corresponde al primer argumento que has pasado a la función range, luego al pasar el número 1, este debería detener la creación de la secuencia hasta dicho número, es decir 1, pero no hay número 1 después del 10. El último argumento determina el incremento entre secuencia, un ejemplo sería incrementar por 2 cada secuencia.

Comparto código de ejemplo:

```py
x = range(10, 30, 2)

for n in x:
  print(n)
```

Comparto fuente que te permitirá conocer aspectos básicos de la función **range**:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

https://pynative.com/python-range-function/

Comment: Editada la respuesta

Comment: Se recomienda citar la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) en las referencias.

Comment: A tu respuesta le falta mucho. ¿Que tendría que modificar el OP para que le funcione?